# Using grp:caps_switch with xkbmap for custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb

I want <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> to function as arrow keys when <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is pressed down. To do this, I pasted the following to the bottom of the `/usr/shar/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file:

```
partial  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "alpha_arrows" {

    key <AC07>  { symbols[Group2]=[ Left,      Left,      Left,      Left      ] };
    key <AC08>  { symbols[Group2]=[ Down,      Down,      Down,      Down      ] };
    key <AC09>  { symbols[Group2]=[ Right,     Right,     Right,     Right     ] };
    key <AD08>  { symbols[Group2]=[ Up,        Up,        Up,        Up        ] };

};
```

I then added the following command to my `.bashrc` file:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:caps_switch
```

This indeed disables <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and allows <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to toggle the caps lock command. My understanding is that holding <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> down should activate the "Group2" key bindings that I set up above... But this simply doesn't happen.

I've tried clearing the cache using `rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*` and the restarting the machine several times. Still no dice. Notably, I was able to swap <kbd>Left-Control</kbd> and <kbd>Left-Super</kbd>, so I know that `xkb/symbols/pc` is the right file to edit.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to check/confirm that "Group2" is activated? As you may be able to tell, I only have a tenuous grasp on how this works.
- Is it valid to just paste that block of code at the bottom of the `xkb/symbols/pc` file?
- Is there an equally easy alternative to remap these keys? I'd also be interested in remapping <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, etc...

**References that have got me this far:**

- http://domwatson.codes/2014/11/who-needs-capslock-anyway-part-2.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153841/how-to-make-altgri-j-k-l-work-properly-as-cursor-keys

**Note:** This question seems to be have been asked in various forms around the internet, and I was hesitant to add more noise to the system. But a lot of what I've read has used `xmodmap` which is now (apparently) outdated. And AutoKey made me want to stab my eyes out.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added my custom layout to the gui in elementary OS Loki.

To add my custom layout I do the following:

1. edit existing xkb/symbols/ru file to add my layout there;
2. edit evdev.xml file to add the appropriate variant there;
3. edit **evdev.lst** file to add the appropriate variant there;
4. edit **base.xml** file to add the appropriate variant there;
5. edit **base.lst** file to add the appropriate variant there;

It seems, you don't do the steps #3,4,5.

Could you try it and report back?

**EDIT:**

1. I've made some testing and ready to say, that the layout definetely **appears in the GUI** after editing evdev.xml AND evdev.lst.
2. The appropriate variant seems to be:
   xkb_symbols "**alpha_arrows**"
   so one should add to evdev.lst the following line:

   alpha_arrows    gb: Doms l33t layout
3. Editing base.xml and base.lst seems to be redundant and unnecessary.

**EDIT2:** Additionally, there **seems to be an error in the initial guide**. One should add to the evdev.xml

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>alpha_arrows</name>
    <shortDescription>endom</shortDescription>
    <description>Dom's l33t layout</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList />
</layout>
```

[image: Screen of Custom Layout in the GUI]